Criticisms of "reductio ad absurdum" argumentation?
Ed Feser, Immortal Souls, pt. 3 ch. 8 says:

[…] reductio ad absurdum arguments, the probative force of which is generally acknowledged.

Which philosophers/logicians do not recognize "the probative force of" "reductio ad absurdum arguments"? What reasons do they give?

See Reductio ad absurdum: in the form "if the assumption that statement P is true or that a certain object with property P exists leads to a contradiction, that the assumption must be rejected" is absolutely safe.

This is closely related to constructivism

See Bouwer's critique:

Brouwer pointed out the validity of the proof method of [the part of the] reductio ad absurdum that can be used to establish negative propositions ¬A. On the other hand, reductio ad absurdum in general cannot be used to establish positive propositions A; the derivation of a contradiction from the assumption ¬A only leads to ¬¬A, which intuitionistically is weaker than A.

See The Constructive Interpretation of Logic for the interpretation of logical conncetives and quantifiers:

∨ (or): to prove P ∨ Q we must either have a proof of P or have a proof of Q.


∃ (there exists):  to prove ∃x P(x) we must construct an object x  and prove that P(x) holds.

The first impacts on LEM: A ∨ ¬A: for Brouwer and Intuitionism, LEM was abstracted from finite situations, then extended without justification to statements about infinite collections.
But it impacts on RAA.
From a constictivistic point of view we have to make a distiction between:

Reductio Ad Absurdum rule: Given a  derivation starting with the temporary
assumption A and concluding with a contradiction (⊥), we can derive ¬A, and


Classical Reductio Ad Absurdum rule: Given a  derivation starting with the temporary assumption ¬A and concluding with a contradiction (⊥), we can derive A, which is equivalent to Double Negation and thus is not valid constructively.

Thus, the constructive point of view rejects the validity of an existence proof based on Classical RAA, i.e. a proof that the assumption that P(x) is false for every x leads to a contradiction is not enough to assert that there is an object x having that property.
In symbols: ∀x ¬P(x) → ⊥ does not imply ∃x P(x), in contrast with the classical interpretation of existence, in which ∃x P(x)  means ¬
∀x ¬P(x).

Did you mean "object x not having that property" at the end?

To complement Mauro's fine answer, the key figures you may want to look at are Errett Bishop and Michael Dummett.  Bishop was able to develop a substantial portion of mathematical analysis in the spirit of constructive mathematics (rejecting the law of excluded middle, i.e., the reductio ad absurdum).  Dummett wrote in a more philosophical vein, and seems to go beyond Bishop in his endorsement of ultrafinitism; see for example this recent question.
